# Full Screen Mode Issue

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Hello I have a simple application that display a video then the user will erase it with the mouse and a message bellow will be displayed everything work good in normal mode but in full screen mode Here's my code any help ?

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Graphics;
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent; 
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.StageDisplayState;
    import flash.events.FullScreenEvent;

    public class MaskTestMain extends MovieClip {

        private var enableMasking:Boolean = true; //set this to false to turn off masking and just draw lines
        private var tempGraphics:Graphics;

        public function MaskTestMain() {

            if(stage) init(null);
            else this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            video.visible = false;
            objectToMask_mc.visible = false;
        }
        private function init(event:Event)
        {
            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
            stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
            stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, onResizeHandler);
            onResizeHandler(null);
            startButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goFullScreenAndStartDraw)
        }
        private function goFullScreenAndStartDraw(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
            stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;

            startButton.visible = false;
            video.visible = true;
            objectToMask_mc.visible = true;
            video.v.play();
            updateMask();
            tempGraphics = drawingBoard_mc.graphics;
            tempGraphics.clear();
            tempGraphics.lineStyle(200, 0xff0000, 1); 
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onStartDrawing);
            stage.addEventListener(FullScreenEvent.FULL_SCREEN, onFullScreenChange);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onStopDrawing);
        }
        private function onFullScreenChange(event:FullScreenEvent):void
        {
                onResizeHandler(null);

        }
        private function onResizeHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            drawingBoard_mc.x = 0;
            maskHolder_mc.y = 0;
            trace("onResizeHandler");
            drawingBoard_mc.x = drawingBoard_mc.y = 0;

            startButton.x = stage.stageWidth/2;
            startButton.y = stage.stageHeight/2;

            maskHolder_mc.x = maskHolder_mc.y = 0;
            video.height = stage.stageHeight;
            video.scaleX = video.scaleY;
            video.x = stage.stageWidth/2 -  video.width/2;
            video.y = 0;


            objectToMask_mc.x = video.x;
            objectToMask_mc.y = video.y;
            objectToMask_mc.width = video.width + 150;
            objectToMask_mc.height = video.height +180;

        }
        //- start drawing lines:
         function onStartDrawing(e:MouseEvent):void {
            tempGraphics.moveTo(mouseX, mouseY);
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onDrawFrame);
        }

        //- stop drawing lines:
         private function onStopDrawing(e:MouseEvent):void {
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onDrawFrame);
        }                   

        //- called on every frame while drawing - draws the next line and calls masking function:
        private function onDrawFrame(e:Event):void {
            tempGraphics.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);    
            updateMask(); 
        }       

        //- when masking is enabled, this uses the dynamic lines to create a mask:
        private function updateMask():void {
            if (enableMasking) {
                //remove all old masks from the maskHolder:
                while (maskHolder_mc.numChildren > 0) {
                    maskHolder_mc.removeChildAt(0);
                }

                objectToMask_mc.mask = null; //clear the previous mask form the object

                //parameters of bitmapData MUST be set to: ([width], [height], true, 0) to get the transparency correct:
                var myBitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight, true, 0);

                drawingBoard_mc.visible = true; //make this visible for creating the bitmap 
                myBitmapData.draw(drawingBoard_mc); //create a bitmap copy of the drawing board
                drawingBoard_mc.visible = false; //hide the drawing board again
                var printBitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(myBitmapData); //create a bitmap from the bitmap data
                printBitmap.smoothing = true; //optional
                var maskClip:MovieClip = new MovieClip; //create a movieclip to act as the new mask
                maskClip.addChild(printBitmap); //add the bitmap copy of the drawing board to the new mask movieclip
                maskClip.cacheAsBitmap = true; //IMPORTANT: mask movieclip cacheAsBitmap = true or this doesn't work
                maskHolder_mc.addChild(maskClip); //add the new mask to the maskHolder
                objectToMask_mc.cacheAsBitmap = true; //IMPORTANT: masked movieclip cacheAsBitmap = true or this doesn't work
                objectToMask_mc.mask = maskClip; //set our new mask on the object 
            }
        }                   




    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make a fullscreen button that will send them to the swf page, which is a different swf that cand send them to the previous page, the swf file is automatically in fullscreen.

This is just one way, though.  Take a look at the components section under videos, and try that if you cant accomplish this through code

Comment: Ok, sorry, can you post a picture of your library? That may help

Comment: For now i just come with around and used HTML Fullscreen instead of flash full scrren and it works fine